# Flymake is not working for me on Windows Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)
  (flymake-reformat-err-line-patterns-from-compile-el compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)
  (append (quote (... ... ... ... ... ...)) (flymake-reformat-err-line-patterns-from-compile-el compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist))
  (defvar flymake-err-line-patterns (append (quote ...) (flymake-reformat-err-line-patterns-from-compile-el compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)) "Patterns for matching error/warning lines.  Each pattern has the form\n(REGEXP FILE-IDX LINE-IDX COL-IDX ERR-TEXT-IDX).\nUse `flymake-reformat-err-line-patterns-from-compile-el' to add patterns\nfrom compile.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "flymake" nil t)
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/elisp/flymake.el" "flymake" nil t)
  require(flymake)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "~/.emacs" nil t)
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/.emacs" "~/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil ",T
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I had to upgrade my Emacs to 23.1 to make it work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yah, it looks like `'flymake` is missing a `(require 'compile)` dependency.  You can resolve by adding that above the `(require 'flymake)` line in your .emacs.